# How to convert XML (String) to a valid document?

Tags: java, exception, xpath, document, domxpath

I have XML as a string and i want to convert it to DOM document in order to parse it using XPath, i use this code to convert one String element to DOM element:

```
public Element convert(String xml) throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException{

        Element sXml =  DocumentBuilderFactory
                .newInstance()
                .newDocumentBuilder()
                .parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(xml.getBytes()))
                .getDocumentElement();


        return  sXml;

    }
```

but what if i want to convert a whole XML file?? i tried casting but it didn't work as you can't convert from Element to a Document(Exception thrown):

**The Exception :**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.DeferredElementImpl cannot be cast to org.w3c.dom.Document
```

**The Code :**

```
public Document convert(String xml) throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException{

        Element sXml =  DocumentBuilderFactory
                .newInstance()
                .newDocumentBuilder()
                .parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(xml.getBytes()))
                .getDocumentElement();


        return (Document) sXml;

    }
```

i also tried this but didn't work:

```
public Document convert(String xml) throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException{

        Document sXml =  DocumentBuilderFactory
                .newInstance()
                .newDocumentBuilder()
                .parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(xml.getBytes()));


        return  sXml;

    }
```

what can i do to fix this problem? and if there is a way in XPath to parse a String rather than a document it also will be fine.

Comment: -1: "Didn't work" is perhaps the most useless thing you can post in a question. *What* didn't work? Did it fail to compile? If yes, paste the *entire* compilation output into your question. Did it throw an exception? If yes, paste the *entire* stack trace into your question. Did it do something else? If yes, describe what you were expecting and how the result was different from what you expected.

Comment: it throws an exception(can't convert from element to document)

Comment: did you read what @kdgregory wrote? _Did it throw an exception? If yes, paste the entire stack trace into your question_

Comment: edited with the exception thrown

Answer (score 5):

Maybe by using this

```
public static Document stringToDocument(final String xmlSource)   
    throws SAXException, ParserConfigurationException, IOException {  
    DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();  
    DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();  

    return builder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(xmlSource)));  
}
```

Comment: remember to have _<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>_ at the begining of the `String`

Comment: No, i tried it before but it just parses the String as a document but the resulted document is not XML one

Comment: @MuhammedRefaat first of all you said _i want to convert it to DOM document_ and then, how is that the document is not xml? what does it mean? You asked for a way of transforming an xml in string to a w3.Document and that is what i gave you. This is even a code i use myself

Comment: @fGo - the document prologue isn't necessary, and in fact may cause problems depending on how the parser treats the `InputSource`. But +1 for trying to help; this code looks like what the OP should be using.

Comment: @fGo I mean the "resulted" document is not XML.
like if you have a String "4", in fact it's an integer but the compiler will read it as a String, i want a way make the compiler read my XML as a document(i have a valid XML but it's in the shape of String).

Comment: @MuhammedRefaat if you want data type validation then you must use a XSD that represent this XML and generate JAXB clases. Then if a tag `<age>5</age>` it'll be assigned to an `int age;`

Comment: @fGo that why i said ("LIKE" if you have)

Comment: Apart from validating the xml against a xsd (with or without jaxb) i don't see you any other kind of automatic validation. anyway, I think is better that you create a new question with this sort of 'validation' you want