# Get attribute called comment from a Node with Java

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing

I need to get these XML-Comments extracted. Especially the criterion comment.
I'm new to XML-Parsing. I'm currently using the standard Java-XML-Parser javax.xml

```
     <criteria>
    <criteria operator="OR" comment="Operation system section">
      <extend_definition comment="SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 12 is installed" definition_ref="oval:org.mitre.oval:def:28211"/>
      <extend_definition comment="SUSE Linux Enterprise Desktop 12 is installed" definition_ref="oval:org.mitre.oval:def:28148"/>
    </criteria>
    <criterion comment="update-test-security-0 is earlier than 0:11.2" test_ref="oval:org.mitre.oval:tst:136394"/>
  </criteria>
```

How can i extract the comments?

Comment: These are not the comments you are looking for. (Without Jedi speak: That are attributes named "comment", but not xml comments).

Comment: Haha, Thank you

So i should get that Information using getAttribute.

Answer (score 0):

To just read all attributes named "comment" I recommend to use XPath via [XMLBeam](http://xmlbeam.org). (Disclosure: I'm affiliated with this project.)

```
public class ReadAttributes {
public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> comments = new XBProjector().io().stream(ReadAttributes.class.getResourceAsStream("data.xml")).evalXPath("//@comment").asListOf(String.class);
        System.out.println(comments);
        }
}
```

This program prints out:

```
[Operation system section, SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 12 is installed, SUSE Linux Enterprise Desktop 12 is installed, update-test-security-0 is earlier than 0:11.2]
```

Answer (score 0):

**If you don't need the whole XML data as a java object and just need the criterion comment attribute, you could use XPath to get it:**

```
XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
return xpath.evaluate("/criteria/criterion/@comment", document);
```

If you have the XML in a string and don't know how to parse it to Document, take a look at: [How to convert XML (String) to a valid document?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16919169/how-to-convert-xml-string-to-a-valid-document)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use JDK's simple XPath feature:

```
String[] args = new String[]{ "//*[@comment]" };
XPathFactory xpf = XPathFactory.newInstance();
XPath xpath = xpf.newXPath();
for( String s: args ){
    XPathExpression xpExp = xpath.compile( "count("+s+")" );
    String res = xpExp.evaluate( source );
    System.out.println( s + ": " + res );
    int n = Integer.parseInt( res );
    for( int i = 1; i <= n; i++ ){
        xpExp = xpath.compile( "(" + s + ")[" + i + "]/@comment" );
        System.out.println(  "comment: " + xpExp.evaluate( source ) );
    }
}
```